# The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

Tags: wcf

I am maintaining a large project that uses a lot of WCF services and when certain users log in to the site they get this error

```
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' '.
```

I don't know what the cause of this could be, nor where to look to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess the authentication is failing for those users

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263150/the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the remote WCF service had an error and the response was of type text/html, which was different from the response type of a success message.  Just for anyone who has this sort of issue in the future.