# How to solve WCF error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, web-services

Why should I get this error

> *The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: 
>   !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
>   < html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">*

**InnerException**

> *The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error*

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Instead of an XML response, your call returned a HTML page - often this is the sign of a "page not found" error or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263150/the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match)

Comment: Sounds like an authentication issue

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons why you are getting this error. From the information you provided in your question it is hard to say what could be the exact reason. In order to debug the problem you could [configure tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx):

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="sdt"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData= "WcfDetailTrace.xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

and then open the generated `WcfDetailTrace.xml` trace file with the provided [`SvcTraceViewer.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) and inspect the exception details.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't say much more than what you've already provided in your question and which, as I explained in my answer, is not enough to determine the cause of the problem. So what happened when you activated tracing as I suggested you? What does the log file contain?

Comment: Alright, would you like to share with us what the error was and how you solved it? It might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: I have given password for WCF service in IIS. In last week I have change it. I doesn't remember to change for WCF service.