# Not getting data from WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I Hosted WCf Service in IIS and made that as independent virtual directory. When I host this service I Can see the Methods of WCF from WCF test client but can't access the data.. 
Could you quickly suggest where I'm going wrong

below is my code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MobServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="ClubConnect.MobService" behaviorConfiguration="MobServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ClubConnect.IMobService"/>
    <endpoint address="ws" name="webHttpBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ClubConnect.IMobService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="http://domain/mobile_app/mobservice.svc" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Error:

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024
>   bytes of the response were: ' '. Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation
>   operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken
>   currentToken, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at IMobService.GetCategoryList() at
>   MobServiceClient.GetCategoryList()

Comment: Are you issuing `GET` request, i mean - are you expecting to hit a WCF url with some param and get result, but you are getting error?

Comment: yes Get request and expecting a hit to WCF URL with Method name and parameters @ArindamNayak Could you suggest where I'm going wrong

Comment: Can you open service URL in browser? If no - Do you have WCF Services -> HTTP Activation feature "on"

Comment: Yes we can open it in browser but while passing parameters and method name I'm getting the error... same service works fine on localhost.. Also Http Activation is on @fly_ua

Comment: Does yur service have authentication? From stack trace it seems issue somewhere in security or you have different behaviours for Server and Client in your config. Please check you have the same onfigs

Comment: @Mukarram , I would suggest, read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263150/the-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match

Comment: No Authentication... will it solve if i Implement Authentication? @fly_ua

Comment: Last idea i have - have you checked your configs for equal settings for bindings and behaviours ?